# Running VB when a row is clicked on a datasheet subform in Microsoft Access 2013

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

So I'm creating a basic database in Microsoft Access 2013. I have a ParentForm, called formLanding, and multiple subforms within that ParentForm. Basically, what I want to happen is when a user clicks on a row within one of the subform datasheets (which display tables like Products and Users), I want to be able to display more information about whatever they clicked on.

Let's say I have subform datasheets called Products, Users, and Locations. If a user were to click on a row within Products, a box/form to the side would show all Users and Locations of the Product. If a user were to click on a row within Locations, the same box would show all Products in that Location.

The reason I want to do this via VB is because I think it'll be easier. I know how to write SQL and VB, but I don't understand Access very well. Rather than trying to link these multiple objects together using their interface I think it'd just be easier to work with VB. I'd also like to be able to run multiple queries sequentially and with parameters, something I haven't figured out how to do in Access yet.

How do I do this? How do I call VB when a user clicks on a row, have my VB queries run and return relevant information based on what they clicked on, and then send that information to another object and have it display it? Is Access built to handle this sort of thing?

Thanks.

EDIT: I wanted to add that the data details I want to display when a row is clicked could include data from multiple tables and return multiple rows. For instance, a Product could have 5 users and 2 locations. I would like to display that information in the same form/report.

Answer (score 0):

You would do this by linking the sub forms to the parent form using the Child / Master properties in the SubForm container.

Assuming you can define a relationship between a Control(Field) in the Parent form and the Data in the sub forms, Access will perform this task automatically.

If you want to Link multiple forms you may need to use the OnCurrent event of the sub forms to change a unbound textbox value on the parent form to force a cascade update of the other subforms.

Answer (score -1):

I can't answer all of your topics, but this string usually works for running more code when certain cells or rows are selected/edited.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("O2:O2")) Is Nothing Then

    Exit Sub


    Else
    'Do the things
```

Or reference a specific sheet and range of cells with 
`Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("R17:R55")`

Comment: This is Access not Excel, they are completely different.